# Laravel 5: check if user belongs to the moderators list before allowing him to edit

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

I am using `Gate` authorization to check if the user has permissions to access or see something.

For example I have a `update-post` gate definition that checks if the user owns the post or owns the sub, if yes, he will be able to see the "Edit" link and access the Edit route. If not, he won't be able to see anything.

I am now trying to add another permissions to check if the user belongs to the "moderators" table, if yes, he will also be able to see the "Edit" link on `subreddit/show`

It works great for the first 2 checks, but fails on the third and the "Edit" link is always visible now, even though I cannot access the edit route of posts that aren't mine or belong to the subreddit I own.

**EDIT:** I have edited `$moderators_list` it now check if the logged in user is a moderator of the subreddit that the post he's viewing. `dd($moderators_list` gets me a list with correct values. But I can't use `$moderators_list->user_id` that will give `Undefined property: Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection::$user_id`

**EDIT 2:** I have fixed the query that gets the user_id of the user who is a moderator in a subreddit. So now using `$moderators_list->user-id` gets me the id of 3 which is the user id of the current logged in. But the gate checking still fails, unable to edit posts in the subreddit I am moderator in.

My tables

```
users: id, name, email...
subreddits: id, user_id...
posts: id, user_id, subreddit_id...
moderators: id, user_id, subreddit_id...
```

This is the `$gate` definitions

```
$gate->define('update-post', function ($user, $post, $moderators_list) {
        // Check if user is subreddit owner
        if ($user->id === $post->subreddit->user->id) {
            return true;
        }

        // Check if user is the post author
        if ($user->id === $post->user_id) {
            return true;
        }

        // Check if user is a moderator of a subreddit
        if ($user->id === $moderators_list->user_id) {
            return true;
        }

        return false;
});
```

And this is `show()` method on `PostsController`

Please note that `dd($moderators_list)` will output a list of all moderators of the subreddit this post is located in, so I am getting the correct result.

```
public function show(Post $post, Subreddit $subreddit, Moderator $moderator)
{
        $post = Post::with('user.votes')->findOrFail($post->id);
        $moderator = Moderator::where('user_id', '=', Auth::id())->first();
        $moderators_list = Moderator::where('subreddit_id', '=', $post->subreddit->id)->where('user_id', '=', Auth::id())->first();

        return view('post/show')->with('post', $post)
                                ->with('moderator', $moderator)
                                ->with('moderators_list', $moderators_list);
}
```

And this is how I check to see if user has access to see the "Edit" link on the view

```
@can('update-post', [$post, $moderator, $moderators_list])
     <a href="{{ action('PostsController@edit', $post->id) }}">Edit</a>
@endcan
```

Comment: In the $gate definition you need to check if the user is a moderator of the subreddit that the user is viewing rather than just check if its a moderator of any subreddit.

Comment: This `Moderator::where('subreddit_id', '=', $post->subreddit->id)->where('user_id', '=', Auth::id())->get()` will get me the correct result when the user is a moderator of the subreddit the post he's viewing. But the permission is still not working, I can still see the edit link on all posts everywhere and I am not being able to edit the posts where I am a moderator.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can check if the user is a moderator directly in the DB:

```
$isModerator = $post->subreddit->moderators()->where('user_id', $user->id)->exists();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$gate->define('update-post', function ($user, $post, $moderators_list) {
        // Check if user is subreddit owner
        if ($user->id === $post->subreddit->user->id) {
            return true;
        }

        // Check if user is the post author
        if ($user->id === $post->user_id) {
            return true;
        }

        // Check if user is a moderator of a subreddit
        if (in_array($user->id, $moderators_list)) { //will need to add ->toArray(); after the ->get() in the $moderators_list query.
            return true;
        }

        return false;
});
```

Now you will need to add ->toArray(); after the ->get() in the $moderators_list query:

```
public function show(Post $post, Subreddit $subreddit, Moderator $moderator)
{
        $post = Post::with('user.votes')->findOrFail($post->id);
        $moderator = Moderator::where('user_id', '=', Auth::id())->first();
        $moderators_list = Moderator::where('subreddit_id', '=', $post->subreddit->id)->get()->toArray;

        return view('post/show')->with('post', $post)
                                ->with('moderator', $moderator)
                                ->with('moderators_list', $moderators_list);
}
```

Comment: This is giving me `in_array() expects parameter 2 to be array, null given`

Comment: Updated my reply with the edit for the `moderators_list`. It gets a list of all of the mods for the subreddit. Then the in_array() will check if your logged in user is in that subreddit's moderator list. I hope it makes sense.