# Laravel 5: SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'users.moderators'

Tags: php, laravel, model, laravel-5, eloquent

I'm guessing it's a Model relations error but I can't seem to pin it down.

I have 4 tables

```
users: id, name, email...
subreddits: id, user_id...
posts: id, title, subreddit_id, user_id...
moderators: id, user_id, subreddit_id...
```

I am trying to get all posts with eager loading 'user.votes' and 'subreddit.moderators'

```
$post = Post::with('user.votes')->with('subreddit.moderators')->findOrFail($post->id);
```

But I keep getting this error

> QueryException in Connection.php line 636:
>
> SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'users.moderators' in 'where clause' (SQL: select * from `users` where `users`.`moderators` in (17))

If I load it with `subreddit` alone, it will work, but I need to get the moderators of the subreddit as well.

EDIT: I removed `moderators` field from `moderators()` method in `Subreddit` Model and replace `App\User` with `App\Moderator` and I am now able to get the subreddit in question and its moderators. However, access `$post->subreddit->moderators->user_id` gives me this error `Undefined property: Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection::$user_id`

These are my Models

`User` Model

```
public function subreddit() {
    return $this->hasMany('App\Subreddit');
}

public function posts() {
    return $this->hasMany('App\Post');
}

public function votes(){
    return $this->hasManyThrough('App\Vote','App\Post');
}

public function moderators(){
    return $this->hasManyThrough('App\Moderator', 'App\Subreddit');
}
```

`Subreddit` Model

```
public function user() {
    return $this->belongsTo('App\User');
}

public function posts() {
    return $this->hasMany('App\Post');
}

public function moderators() {
    return $this->hasMany('App\User', 'moderators');
}
```

`Post` Model

```
public function user() {
    return $this->belongsTo('App\User');
}
```

`Moderator` Model

```
public function subreddit() {
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Subreddit');
}

public function user() {
    return $this->belongsTo('App\User');
}

public function posts() {
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Post');
}
public function subreddit() {
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Subreddit');
}

public function votes() {
    return $this->hasMany('App\Vote');
}

public function moderators() {
    return $this->hasMany('App\Moderator');
}
```

`Vote` Model

```
public function user() {
    return $this->belongsTo('App\User');
}

public function posts() {
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Post');
}
```

Gate authorization in `AuthServiceProvider`

```
$gate->define('update-post', function ($user, $post, $isModerator) {
        // Check if user is subreddit owner
        if ($user->id === $post->subreddit->user->id) {
            return true;
        }

        // Check if user is the post author
        if ($user->id === $post->user_id) {
            return true;
        }

        // Check if user is a moderator of a subreddit
        if ($isModerator) {
            return true;
        }

        return false;
});
```

Comment: Do you have a "moderators" column in your User model?

Comment: I have a `moderators()` method in in the User model with this `return $this->hasManyThrough('App\Moderator', 'App\Subreddit');`

Comment: Yes, but your `moderators()` function in the `Subreddit` model looks for a `moderators` key on your user model (you specified "moderator" as the second argument, which is the foreign key)

Comment: I see. No, I don't have any `moderators` field anywhere in my db. Should I remove it and use `App\Moderator` instead of App\User?

Comment: @Drown I have updated my original post, please have a look.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want a collection of user IDs for all moderators, use this:

```php
$ids = Post::findOrFail($id)->subreddit->moderators()->lists('user_id');
```

---

If you want to check if the given user is a moderator on the subreddit, use this:

```php
$subreddit = Post::findOrFail($id)->subreddit;

$isModerator = $subreddit->moderators()->where('user_id', $user->id)->exists();
```

Comment: Thank you very much. I am not getting any errors which is nice. But I am using `ids` to check if the user if a moderator that belongs to the subreddit `if ($user->id === $ids)` but that doesn't seem to be working, I am not being able to edit in the subreddits where I am a moderator.

Comment: Thanks again, `dd($subreddit)` gives 'No query results for model [App\Post].' so I am still unable to check whether the user is a moderator or not. And I've edited my post and added the function where I'm checking this.

Comment: @Halnex - Well, you obviously don't have a post with the specified ID.

Comment: I am positive that the post id I am visiting exists. 100%

Comment: In `Post::findOrFail($id)`, where does the `$id` come from?

Comment: I use `$post-id` and Model injection `Post $post` - also `dd(ids)` works

Comment: Method injection, or route model binding? If you're just type hinting for `Post`, you'll get an empty post model whose `$id` is `null`.

Comment: I am using route model binding. Using this `Post::findOrFail($post->id)->subreddit->moderators()->where('user_id', Auth::id())->lists('user_id')` I am able to retrieve the logged in user_id of the subreddit mod. But I still can't compare it against `$user->id` and using `exists()` method gives an error.

Comment: I don't wanna be a pain in the neck but ultimately I am trying to solve this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32994444/laravel-5-check-if-user-belongs-to-the-moderators-list-before-allowing-him-to-e with whatever method. I've been at it for days.

Comment: Why are you reloading the post if you already have it? `$subreddit = $post->subreddit;`

Comment: You're right, I didn't know I could do that. It's solved! Mods can now edit posts in the subreddit's they're assigned to. Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: If you'd like please comment on the other thread so I can mark it as the answer too. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32994444/laravel-5-check-if-user-belongs-to-the-moderators-list-before-allowing-him-to-e